# PUT is not allowed - REST Assured with Swagger

Tags: testing, junit, swagger, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am running API Tests using REST Assured and Swagger, using the Swagger Request Validator package of Atlassian (https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator)

I experince weird problem trying to test some PUT Api:

```
        given()

            .pathParam("id", "1")
            .headers("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    .when()
            .queryParams("id", "1",
                         "package", "Yogev")

            .put("/packages/{id}.json")
    .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(200);
}
```

Here is the swagger json:

```
"/packages/{id}.json": {
  "put": {
    "description": "Updates p....
```

And this is the error:
`com.atlassian.oai.validator.restassured.SwaggerValidationFilter$SwaggerValidationException: Validation failed.
[ERROR] PUT operation not allowed on path '/packages/1.json'.
        at com.atlassian.oai.validator.restassured.SwaggerValidationFilter.filter(SwaggerValidationFilter.java:61)
        at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
        at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1731)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:815)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1737)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:815)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.put(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:178)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.put(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at ApiTests.PatientsTest.PatientProfileTest.updatePatientProfile(PatientProfileTest.java:27)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)`

The main thing:

```
[ERROR] PUT operation not allowed on path '/packages/1.json'.
```

As you can see, I do have the PUT operation specified in my json, but still, the validation filter doesn't recognize it.
POST and GET works great for now.

Comment: do you have web.xml set up? does it allow PUT ?

Comment: Indeed, it's the swagger.json I added.

Answer (score 1):

You are using queryParams, so your request is smth like this: PUT /packages/1.json?id=1&package=Yogev with an empty request body. Maybe you should use formParams?

Comment: I tried, same result, still [ERROR] PUT operation not allowed on path '/packages/1.json'.

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix it finally?